# How to get notification count using NotificationContentProvider on Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv

I've implemented a way to get notifications using NotificationContentProvider. This is the code i'm using

```
private static final Uri NOTIF_COUNT_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.tv.notifications.NotificationContentProvider/notifications/count");
private static final String COLUMN_COUNT = "count";

...

private int count;
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(NOTIF_COUNT_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
   int index = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COUNT);
   count = data.getInt(index);
}
if (c != null) {
   c.close();
}
```

The problem I'm having an exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: App does not have permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS
```

I've tried adding this permission in manifest and asking in runtime but none of this work. How can I get notification count? I also need to get unseen notifications but I haven't found a way to do it

Answer (score 3):

In terms of Android TV, I think you are going to need to be a system app (move the install directory from /data/app to /system/priv-app) and to set up a priv-app permission file in /etc/permissions whose contents look like:

```
<permissions>
    <privapp-permissions package="your app package name">
        <permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    </privapp-permissions>
</permissions>
```